# VBA Excel - Number Format

Tags: excel, vba

For the `Else` statement, can I ask if how can I make the `coLRN` be like `0003`? The result of the this line `txtBox_LRN.Text = "NS" & Year(Date) & coLRN` in the code is `NS20213` where `3` is the count of `coLRN`. I just need to make the `3` be like `0003`.

```
Dim srch As String
srch = "*" & "NS" & Year(Date) & "*"
coLRN = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("STUDENTS_INFO").Columns(3), srch)
                
  If coLRN = 0 Then
     txtBox_LRN.Text = "NS" & Year(Date) & "0001"
  Else
     txtBox_LRN.Text = "NS" & Year(Date) & coLRN
 End If
```

Comment: `Format(coLRN,"0000")`

Comment: @TimWilliams it worked! Thank you!